# Updating dead link in SO too minor of an edit?

Tags: discussion

I just want to make sure I'm using Stack Overflow correctly. Anytime I come across a link that is broken, I replace it with the appropriate functioning link. However, sometimes when I do this I notice that some people move to reject my edit. To me, functioning links are very important, but is this too minor of an edit? Are there certain contexts where fixing a dead link is more important than others?

Comment: Link to an example of a rejected edit?

Comment: The link [you changed here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1905767) works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: It all depends on who stumble on the edit. I, personally always accept update of dead links when the new link is good and the former was rotten for real. But some don't.

Comment: That link works fine for me too, but being one of the reviewers that accepted it, I can tell you, I only accepted it because I think a link to a readme is better than to the repository file listing. Otherwise I would have rejected it too.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: It's not a link to the readme, persay. It just adds an anchor that jumps the page *down* to the readme. Very, very minor. It's not like scrolling down past the tree is an ordeal. Besides, in the context, it was **not** referring to the readme, but the program as a whole.

Comment: Good to hear. I've edited multiple links, because to me nothing is more frustrating than clicking a broken link, and I don't want other users to have that experience.

Comment: @animuson - it adds an anchor, but the former link resulted in a 404 error.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg It does not 404: http://i.imgur.com/Awwnun6.png

Comment: @Danny Beckett this was the original link:  https://github.com/defunkt/exception_logger/tree/master

Comment: Hmmmmmm, that's weird. When I clicked it from the post it 404d. Now it works. Maybe there was a typo all along?

Comment: Ah, it was that there was an 'https'...when I delete that from the 404'd link in the browser, it loads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll approve edits that change a broken link (I'll test it) to a working one, with some caveats:

- Does the link just look *hammered*, rather than completely down, and it was changed to a mirror or copy?
- Did the edit just add an anchor, when it wasn't really necessary?

Make sure you call out what you changed in your edit comments. Link changes aren't real obvious in the standard diff viewer, and it can look like you didn't change anything.

If you're consistent in your edits, any variability is probably around who's reviewing your edits.

Comment: Interesting. I generally try to find the same page and link it (assuming the URL is all that changed) but in some cases if it's a link to a blog about some Ruby method, and that blog is no longer on the interwebs, I'll revise the wording and link to the API or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

If there are other things to fix in the post, fix them!

If you do an edit like `hi i hv this link (broken link)` -> `hi i hv this link (fixed link)` it will be too minor. Instead, edit it like `I have this link: (fixed link)`.

(obviously this is a very small scenario but it is just an example.)

Edit: real example:

> is possible from a desktop Java application redirect to a page and
>   auto complete the login form? I was trying to make a login, submit the
>   form of the url, but I can not. Here is a link about foo and barring
>   the baz (broken link.) the idea is to redirect to a web page, skipping
>   the login. Sorry for my English.

Instead of simply replacing the broken link, do something like this:

> Is it possible, from a desktop Java application, to redirect to a page
>   and auto complete the login form? I was trying to make a login, and
>   submit the form of the url, but I could not. Here is a link about foo
>   and barring the baz (fixed link.) The idea is to redirect to a web
>   page, skipping the login.

Comment: Makes total sense. How would you comment about that in your edit comment?

Comment: @aceofbassgreg "Fixed broken link, grammar" or something